# How to use GTK PrintOperation to print an image

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, gtk3

I am developing an application and want to enable printing. The data to be printed will be a Kivy Widget. I am attempting to do this using the GTK PrintOperation to print the image of the Widget. I have found many examples of how to use the PrintOperation to print text, but cannot figure out how to use it to print an image.

Here is a minimal code to simulate my issue:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

import cairo
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    Image:
        id: img
        pos_hint: {'top':1, 'center_x':0.5}
        size_hint: 1, 0.75
        source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/filechooser_folder'
        keep_ratio: True
        allow_stretch: True
    Button:
        text: 'Print'
        size_hint: 1, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'y':0, 'center_x':0.5}
        on_release: app.do_print()
'''

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def do_print(self):
        pd = Gtk.PrintOperation()
        pd.set_n_pages(1)
        pd.connect("draw_page", self.draw_page)
        result = pd.run(
            Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG, None)
        print(result)  # handle errors etc.

    def draw_page(self, operation=None, context=None, page_nr=None):
        ctx = context.get_cairo_context()

        # get the image data to be printed and save it to a png file
        img_widget = self.root.ids.img
        img_widget.export_to_png('tmp.png')

        # make cairo ImageSurface from the png file
        surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png('tmp.png')
        ctx.set_source_surface(surface)

TestApp().run()
```

When the above code is run, click on the `Print` Button, then click on `Preview` in the print dialog that pops up. That triggers the `draw_page()` method, but the preview does not show the image. Any idea of how to get the image to display in the preview??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just missing a line at the end of the `draw_page()` method. Adding:

```
ctx.paint()
```

at the end of that method has it working now.